# Pancake sorting problem – Is computing f(n) NP-hard?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, computer-science

The so-called Pancake flipping problem first discussed by Jacob E. Goodman [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318260) yields two entangled problems:

1. MIN-SBPR (Sorting By Prefix Reversals) - Given a permutation, find the smallest sequence of flips sorting the permutation.
2. Compute $f(n)$ - For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, what is the maximum number of flips required to sort any permutation of size $n$?

This [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000015000124) shows that the first problem is NP-hard.

Now, my question is:
Is it known whether the second problem is NP-hard as well? Is there any paper on the NP-hardness of the second problem?

For me, it seems like the second problem is kind of stronger than the first one. Does the NP-hardness of that one follow from the first one in some way? You cannot just check each permutation using the first one since there are $n!$ many permutations.

Comment: If I'm reading the definitions correctly, $f$ is OEIS [A058986](https://oeis.org/A058986). There are sufficiently many references there that I haven't tried to skim them all for discussion of complexity, but the `hard` tag and the small number of entries suggest that it's plausible that the problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Yes, the OEIS is correct, you can also find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting). I also think that is should be NP-hard but I wonder if it was proven yet.

Comment: The second one doesn't follow from the first one in any simple way. For example, it is conceivable that for every $n$, it is easy to identify a *worst-case* permutation and determine how many flips it requires, even though an *arbitrary* permutation is hard to analyze. (I doubt that this is actually true, but the point is that there's no simple way to rule it out.)

Comment: Your question is a bit confused.  You are asking if some sequences is easily computable.  Do you mean $n$ in unary of in binary?  Why are you thinking of NP-hardness, not #P-hardness which is more appropriate for a counting problem?  Do you know any sequence which is NP-hard to compute?  If you don't have good answers to these questions, you might like to read my ICM paper first:  https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/ICM-paper9.pdf

Comment: Problems that take an integer as an input are rarely NP-hard, see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/is-there-a-natural-problem-on-the-naturals-that-is-np-complete

Comment: For the second problem, if $n$ is given in unary, then $f(n)$ is (trivially) computable in FP/poly, hence it cannot be NP-hard unless $\mathrm{NP\subseteq P/poly}$ (and the polynomial hierarchy collapses to $\mathrm{O_2^P}$).

Comment: How should $f(n)$ for n given in unary be "trivially" computable in poly? Please note that $f(n)$ is only known for $1 \leq n \leq 19$ yet.

Comment: @TimothyChow , that one makes sense to me, but I'm wondering if there is any known complexity unless being in NP (obviously)... thank you so far.

Comment: @IgorPak , thank you for these comments. I'll probably have to check those things out first. I'm asking for the problem of computing the described $f(n)$ for $n$ in binary or unary. Anyway, my question is more about whether there is any known complexity at all.